# Oracle APEX: Session state protection violation error on Display Only page item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I'm trying to update `Display Only` page item with a dynamic action on one select lists and want to display the value in that display only item.

My code works and page item gets set but once I try to submit the page I get an error: `Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P1_TEST_ITEM. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance.`

I know for hidden items I can just turn off the `Value Protected` but that is different for `Display Only` page items as there is no option to turn off value protected. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 4):

There is a doc on MOS (1461271.1) explaining this is expected behavior since apex 4.1.1
Here are some workarounds

- Define item as text
- Set Advanced > Custom Attributes to `readonly` OR Advanced > CSS Classes to `apex_disabled`

Alternatively, if you want to use Read Only, then you could use a computation on page submit instead of a dynamic action.

Answer (score 0):

Simply  turn off "Send On Page Submit" under settings of that item and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to turn off "Send on Submit" - but if the field is display only and must be submited - then create a hidden item to hold the value and submit that.